# Intellij showing instanceof as false, when it is actually true

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

I have a Labels enum which implements Label interface. But when I am comparing an element in that enum with Label interface using instanceof , intellij is showing false. But the whole if condition is evaluating to true!
Attaching the screenshot. Is it a bug in intellij or am I missing something obvious here?
[image]

Comment: The thing is `&&` is a short-circuiting operator, so the value being displayed there must be stale. Or, perhaps the compiler uses negated logic. You might examine the bytecode if you're really curious. Provide a MCVE and perhaps someone can be more definitive.

Comment: Looks like `other` is an instance of `Labels`, not `Label` according to the variable display.

Comment: @JimGarrison Labels is an enum implementing Label interface. The whole condition is evaluated true which is correct. My concern is intellij showing other instanceof Label as false, but the whole return condition as true

Comment: Looks like a bug in IntelliJ then

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You are right. Its the stale data. When I evaluate it, the value is true. Looks like an issue with intellij not updating the value

Comment: Maybe you should try the full path of your class like `other instanceof your.package.of.Label`?